# Why my external javascript file cannot link to my html?

Tags: javascript, html

I've already pretty well at html and css. Now i considering learn JS and when i link my html file to the JS file, it's not working.

Here's my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Java Script</title>
    <script scr="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--<h1>Hello</h1>
    -->
    <script>
      alert("if this page blank, external js file not executed!")
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here's my javascript

```
document.write("works!")
```

It's pretty simple, just want to know if it works or not, please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: is `script.js` in the same folder as your .html file?

Comment: there is a typo here <script scr="script.js"></script> it should be <script src="script.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct word is src (source), modify this line:

```js
scr="script.js"
```

```js
src="script.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script scr="script.js"></script>
```

is what you have...

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

should work...

```js
document.write("Works!");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Java Script</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--<h1>Hello</h1>
    -->
    <script>
      alert("if this page blank, external js file not executed!")
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```